# Подсчет операци в определенный период времени

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Коллеги, помогите сформировать DataFrame исходя из заданного условия.

Имеется исходный DataFrame:

```
ID   №Policy   Request     Request date     Decision
123   23ff      10000     2018-01-28 11:36    0
123   23ff      10000     2018-01-29 10:00    5000
123   42rd      25000     2018-06-18 15:10    25000
123   42rd      30000     2018-08-18 18:00    30000
345   23ff      15000     2018-01-28 12:00    10000 
345   27fg      50000     2018-09-30 17:35     0
345   81er      30000     2018-09-30 10:15    10000
345   81er      30000     2018-10-20 11:30    10000
678   12rt      55000     2018-12-01 09:25    0
678   12rt      55000     2018-12-15 12:00    45000
```

Нужно подсчитать кол-во решений (Decisions), принятых по каждому ID в рамка №Policy, однако со следующим ограничением - если решение по ID в рамках одинакового №Policy было принято в течение одного месяца нескольок кол-во раз то такое решение равно 1 (т.е. в течение месяца на одного ID в рамках одного №Policy может приходиться несколько решений 2, 3 или более - если все сделано в рамках одного месяца то независимо от кол-во запросов нужно считать, что это 1 решение).

Результат примерно должен получиться следующим

```
ID   №Policy   Request     Request date     Decision       count
    123   23ff      10000     2018-01-28 11:36    0          0   
    123   23ff      10000     2018-01-29 10:00    5000       1
    123   42rd      25000     2018-06-18 15:10    25000      1
    123   42rd      30000     2018-08-18 18:00    30000      1
    345   23ff      15000     2018-01-28 12:00    10000      1
    345   27fg      50000     2018-09-30 17:35     0         1
    345   81er      30000     2018-09-30 10:15    10000      0
    345   81er      30000     2018-10-20 11:30    10000      1
    678   12rt      55000     2018-12-01 09:25    0          0
    678   12rt      55000     2018-12-15 12:00    45000      1
```

Какой алгоритм тут прописать ума не приложу :(

Comment: можете пояснить почему в результирующем DF в первой строке `count: 0`, а в шестой: `count: 1`?

Comment: в первой строке 0, потому что через 1 день было принято решение повтороное - №Policy и ID совпадают.... в шестой строке было принято решение просто кредит не был одобрен (0) - но решение то принято и из-за этого оно считается как 1 решение. Сама суть заключается в следующем - если кредитное решение по одному и тому же клиенту в рамках одного и того-же контракта (№Policy) было принято несколько раз в течение 30 дней, то оно должно считаться как 1 решение...

Comment: было бы гораздо проще агрегировать строки так, чтобы в итоге осталось по одной строке для каждого `ID`, `NPolicy`, `Request_month`

Comment: вы имеете в виду удалить повторящиеся в рамках одного периода? что-то вроде drop_duplicates?

Comment: В текущей постановке задачи - это сложно реализовать, потому что логика расчета `count` различается. Если бы мы всегда начинали счёт `count` с `1` и во всех последующих строках для одного `ID` и `NPolicy` за тот же месяц ставили бы 0. Тогда логика была бы одинаковой и реализовать такую логику - проще

Comment: Можно какой-угодно сделать результатирующий датафрейм (я просто привел как пример). Главная цель - учесть всего 1 раз кредитное решение, которое принято в течение месяца по одному и тому-же ID и NPolicy

Comment: Можно начинать счет с 1....я просто действительно немного сглупил с результатирующим примером!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
In [209]: df['count'] = (df.groupby(['ID','NPolicy',pd.Grouper(key='Request_date', freq='MS')])
                           ['Decision']
                           .cumcount().eq(0).astype('int'))

In [210]: df
Out[210]:
    ID NPolicy  Request        Request_date  Decision  count
0  123    23ff    10000 2018-01-28 11:36:00         0      1
1  123    23ff    10000 2018-01-29 10:00:00      5000      0
2  123    42rd    25000 2018-06-18 15:10:00     25000      1
3  123    42rd    30000 2018-08-18 18:00:00     30000      1
4  345    23ff    15000 2018-01-28 12:00:00     10000      1
5  345    27fg    50000 2018-09-30 17:35:00         0      1
6  345    81er    30000 2018-09-30 10:15:00     10000      1
7  345    81er    30000 2018-10-20 11:30:00     10000      1
8  678    12rt    55000 2018-12-01 09:25:00         0      1
9  678    12rt    55000 2018-12-15 12:00:00     45000      0
```

Comment: спасибо, вроде все правильно. А такой вопрос если я захочу поменять период, скажем взять не в течение месяца, а в течение 1.5 месяцев или скажем 20 дней...как возможно это сделать?

Comment: [здесь полная таблица "offset aliases"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases), которые можно использовать в параметре `freq`. Можно также указывать число периодов, например `freq='10D'` или `freq='2W'`. Если не получится разобраться - задайте здесь новый вопрос - попробуем разобраться вместе ;)

Comment: Огроменное спасибо!!!!! Очень помогли, как всегда :)